# When do relationships / backrefs become usable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having a difficult time understanding how relationships / backrefs work.
I seem to be missing the point regarding how to make them 'live' so I keep getting errors like:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decid'.

These tables are 1 to 1 forming a heirachy.
I have an SQLite db and the following classes defined.

```
class Person(DECLARATIVE_BASE):

    __tablename__ = 'person'
    __table_args__ = ({'sqlite_autoincrement': True})

    idperson = Column(INTEGER, autoincrement=True,
                      primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    lastname = Column(VARCHAR(45), index=True, nullable=False)
    firstname = Column(VARCHAR(45), index=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return "<Person(%(idperson)s)>" % self.__dict__


class Schoolmember(DECLARATIVE_BASE):

    __tablename__ = 'schoolmember'

    person_id = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey("person.idperson"),
                       index=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    decid = Column(VARCHAR(45), unique=True, nullable=False)
    type = Column(VARCHAR(20), nullable=False)

    person = relationship("Person", foreign_keys=[person_id],
                          backref=backref("schoolmember", uselist=False))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return "<Schoolmember(%(person_id)s)>" % self.__dict__


class Student(DECLARATIVE_BASE):

    __tablename__ = 'student'

    person_id = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey("schoolmember.person_id"),
                      autoincrement=False, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    studentnum = Column(VARCHAR(30), unique=True, nullable=False)
    year = Column(INTEGER, nullable=False)
    graduated = Column(BOOLEAN, default=0, nullable=False)

    schoolmember = relationship("Schoolmember", foreign_keys=[person_id],
                                backref=backref("student", uselist=False))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return "<Student(%(person_id)s)>" % self.__dict__
```

I don't understand why here I can't access schoolmember from Student.
I was expecting declaritive to cascade up the relationships.

```
newstu = Student()
newstu.studentnum = '3456'
newstu.schoolmember.decid = 'fred.frog'  # Error, 'NoneType' object
```

The following works, but only by stomping over the relationships defined in the class?
Do I *need* to do it this way?

```
s = Schoolmember(decid = 'fred.frog')
newstu = Student(schoolmember=s, studentnum='3456')
```

I don't 'get' what's is going on. I'm trying to understand the principals involved so I don't get bamboozled by the next problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your first example doesn't work is because when you initialize student there is no schoolmember associated with it. SQLAlchemy doesn't automatically generate this for you.  If you wanted to, every time you create a `Student` object for it to automatically create a new schoolmember, you could do that inside of an `__init__`. In addition, if you wanted it to work you could do something like:

```
student = Student()
schoolmember = Schoolmember()
student.studentnum = 3456
student.schoolmember = schoolmember
student.schoolmember.decid = 'fred.frog'
```

An `__init__` method could help also, if this is behavior you want every time.

```
def __init__(self, studentnum=None, year=None, graduated=None, schoolmember=None):
    # If no schooolmember was provided, automatically generate one.
    self.schoolmember = schoolmember or Schoolmember()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, but when you do `student.schoolmember = schoolmember` aren't you killing the two-way signalling that SQLA is supposed to have set up?  Regarding the init method, isn't the init in BASE going to get stomped on by that?

Comment: 1. No, you are not.

2. There isn't much of an `__init__` method for your Base class. It basically just sets all the attributes to `None`.